# Python 3: Accessing Parent Attributes, Linter Error

Tags: python, inheritance, pylint, linter

I have some trouble accessing parent attributes appropriately in Python 3.8 with VS Code and PyLint.

PyLint gives me an Error in the second file in the pseudo code listed below.

**file 1:**

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, parentAttr):
        self.parentAttr= parentAttr
```

**file 2:**

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, parentAttr, childAttr):
        super().__init__(parentAttr)
        self.childAttr= childAttr

    def anyFunction(self):
```

In the next line (line 7) the Linter underlines "self." in red and says:

Access to member 'parentAttr' before its definition line 8. pylint(access-member-before-definition)

```
        tmp = self.parentAttr
        self.parentAttr= tmp
```

Code works as it should. But what is the way how I should do such things correctly, without getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you don't have a typo on line 7 of file 2, or on line 3 of file 1? Are you importing the "Parent" class you think you're importing? I tried reproducing your issue and vscode+pylint does not complain about your code on my machine.

[image]

I honestly don't see why it would, You're doing the right thing, at least in the pseudo-code you gave. If it complains, it must be because of a typo somewhere, and a potential bug in your code that you haven't detected yet.

Comment: I see. I put both files in a smaller directory (unchanged). There I don't have these Error. I figured out that the import of the parent class is detected as error from pylint somehow. "Unable to import 'Parent'pylint(import-error)". It has the same folder structure. Weird.

Comment: I found the issue. 
In the directory where I got the problem, an empty, autogenerated file "__init__.py" caused the issue. I removed this file. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Olivier -- I can't replicate this given your pseudo code either in a single file or multiple files.

There are sometimes issues pylint can't handle, but this is simple enough that it should be no problem.

In more complicated examples your options are things like:

1. create a dummy class var (that is, outside of the init function) that is overwritten when `__init__()` is called
2. manually suppress the pylint warning using `# pylint: disable=access-member-before-definition` or the short code form if you have it eg `# pylint: disable=E1101`
3. investigate abstract base classes
4. get a proper plyint plugin for your specific use case (eg django's) that has additional logic to handle those specific dynamic attributes